# Action.Submit is not working for bot framework

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service, adaptive-cards

[image: Attached image is of bot emulator on clicking the submit button.]

I have created an adaptive card using the following code. However on clicking the submit button, the bot throws error.

```
var card = new AdaptiveCard();
card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock() { Text = "May I know who I am chatting with?", Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Medium, Weight = AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder, HorizontalAlignment = AdaptiveHorizontalAlignment.Left });
card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveImage() { UrlString = "https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C510BAQHDcYycRMpKWQ/company-logo_200_200/0?e=2159024400&v=beta&t=MRb3ZSGGATtJvp6s6XQt3r_SqyhORkaleuB3bUWVe6g", Size = AdaptiveImageSize.Medium, HorizontalAlignment= AdaptiveHorizontalAlignment.Right }) ;
card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock() { Text = "Name", Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Medium, Weight = AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder });
card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextInput() { Style = AdaptiveTextInputStyle.Text, Id = "Name", Placeholder = "First Last"});
card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock() { Text = "Mobile number:", Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Medium, Weight = AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder });
card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextInput() { Style = AdaptiveTextInputStyle.Tel, Id = "Mobile number", Placeholder = "xxx.xxx.xxxx" });
card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock() { Text = "Email:", Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Medium, Weight = AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder });
card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextInput() { Style = AdaptiveTextInputStyle.Email, Id = "Email", Placeholder = "youremail@example.com" });
card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock() { Text = "Your Company Name:", Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Medium, Weight = AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder});
card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextInput() { Style = AdaptiveTextInputStyle.Text, Id = "Your Company Name" });
card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock() { Text = "Message:", Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Medium, Weight = AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder});
card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextInput() { Style = AdaptiveTextInputStyle.Text, Id = "Message", IsMultiline = true });
card.Actions.Add(new AdaptiveSubmitAction() {Title = "Submit", Data = { } });

return new Attachment()
{
    ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
    Content = card
};
```

Comment: Can you post the error that is thrown?

Comment: I have attached the image of bot emulator output on clicking the submit button in the post. Please check, if that helps.

Comment: @ShwetanjaliDubey - Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your question? Please have a look at the handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (Since there are multiple people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @ShwetanjaliDubey - Are you still working on this?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Yes, I am still working... the submit button adaptive card is not working..

Comment: @ShwetanjaliDubey - I'm sorry to hear that. What is your question?

Comment: The issue is now resolved. Thanks!

Comment: @ShwetanjaliDubey - Excellent. Would you like to post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I created Adaptive card-

```
public static Attachment PersonalInfo()
    {
        var card = new AdaptiveCard("1.0");

        card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock() { Text = "Sure. While I fetch that, may I know you a little?", Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Medium, Weight = AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder, HorizontalAlignment = AdaptiveHorizontalAlignment.Left });
        //card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock() { Text = "If yes, please fill in the form below and click SUBMIT.", Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Medium, Weight = AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder, HorizontalAlignment = AdaptiveHorizontalAlignment.Left });
        //card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock() { Text = "If no, please click CANCEL at the end", Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Medium, Weight = AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder, HorizontalAlignment = AdaptiveHorizontalAlignment.Left });
        //card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveChoiceSetInput() { Id = "Choose", Style = AdaptiveChoiceInputStyle.Expanded, Choices = new List<AdaptiveChoice>() { new AdaptiveChoice() { Title = "Yes", Value = "Yes" }, new AdaptiveChoice() { Title = "No", Value = "No" } } });
        //card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveImage() { UrlString = "https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C510BAQHDcYycRMpKWQ/company-logo_200_200/0?e=2159024400&v=beta&t=MRb3ZSGGATtJvp6s6XQt3r_SqyhORkaleuB3bUWVe6g", Size = AdaptiveImageSize.Medium, HorizontalAlignment= AdaptiveHorizontalAlignment.Right }) ;
        //card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock() { Text = "Name", Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Medium, Weight = AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder });
        card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextInput() { Style = AdaptiveTextInputStyle.Text, Id = "Name", Placeholder = "Name", IsMultiline = true, IsRequired = true });            
        card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextInput() { Style = AdaptiveTextInputStyle.Tel, Id = "Mobile number", Placeholder = "Mobile number", IsMultiline = true });            
        card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextInput() { Style = AdaptiveTextInputStyle.Email, Id = "Email", Placeholder = "Email ID", IsMultiline = true,  });            
        card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextInput() { Style = AdaptiveTextInputStyle.Text, Id = "Your Company Name", Placeholder = "Your Company Name", IsMultiline = true });
        card.Actions.Add(new AdaptiveSubmitAction() { Title = "SUBMIT", Style = "positive", Id = "submit", Data = "submit", DataJson = "{\"submit\":\"submit\"}"});
        card.Actions.Add(new AdaptiveSubmitAction() { Title = "CANCEL", Style = "negative", Id = "cancel", Data = "cancel", DataJson = "{\"cancel\":\"cancel\"}" });

        return new Attachment()
        {
            ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
            Content = card
        };
    }
```

Then in the beginning of OnTurnAsyc Activity-

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(turnContext.Activity.Text))
        {
            dynamic value = turnContext.Activity.Value;
            if (value != null)
            {
                if (value["submit"] == "submit")
                {
                    //bool flag = true;
                    isFormSubmit = true;
                    string text = value["submit"];  // The property will be named after your text input's ID
                    text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) ? "." : text; // In case the text input is empty
                    turnContext.Activity.Text = text;
                }
                else if (value["cancel"] == "cancel")
                {
                    isFormCancel = true;
                    string text = value["cancel"];  // The property will be named after your text input's ID
                    text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) ? "." : text; // In case the text input is empty
                    turnContext.Activity.Text = text;
                }
            }
```

}